# Xcode missing inline test results

Tags: objective-c, unit-testing, xcode, octest

Everywhere there are pretty pictures of failing tests shown inline in the code editor, like in [Peepcodes Objective-C for Rubyist screencast](http://peepcode.com/products/objective-c-for-rubyists) and in apples own [technical documentation](http://developer.apple.com/mac/articles/tools/unittestingwithxcode3.html):

[image: Test result shown inline]
<sub>(source: [apple.com](http://devimages.apple.com/images/articles/unittestingwithxcode3/figure07.jpg))</sub>

When I build my test-target, all I get is a little red icon down in the right corner, stating something went wrong. When clicking on it, I get the Build Results, where I can start to hunt for test results.

Do anyone have a clue on what´s wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at your Xcode preferences. Under the Building tab you want to change your settings for Message Bubbles.

This works for Xcode 3.1 which it looks like the image you've shown. Xcode 3.2 has a different style of bubble and doesn't have this preference.

Comment: I have Xcode 3.2.1. The screenshot is taken from apples site. Does that mean there is no inline results for me?

Answer (score 1):

Press "Cmd =" to travel between build results, you should see a warning.

Also, that specific warning seems like it's from the static analyzer - you turn that on by going to project preferences and checkmarking "run static analyzer" or by using the "Build and Analyze" option.

Comment: "Cmd =" and "Cmd +" was a good tip, but I would prefer the red bubbles, though :-)

Answer (score 0):

Try Cmd-Shift-H to show all message bubbles.